Reducing editor lag in Vue2
When editing a large amount of content, the editor will lag and be very slow. I tried replacing multiple versions and removing some plugins, but it did not work.
<template>
  <div class="st_editor" ref="stEditor">
    <ckeditor
      ref="ckeditor"
      :value="editorData"
      :editor="editor"
      :config="editorConfig"
      :disabled="!isEdit"
      @ready="onReady"
      @input="onEditorInput"
      @destroy="onEditorDestroy"
      @blur="onBlurFn"
    ></ckeditor>
    <!-- <div class="stEditorCopy"></div> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2'
import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor'

How can I improve the execution speed of my editor?

Not sure you'll be able to do anything with that kind of issue besides trying something totally different.
